# Spring way of Javassist

Tags: spring, javassist, cglib

What is the Spring way of code piece which is written in Javassist. I know that Spring is using CGLib but I am sure that there are some useful good practices to follow for spring world.

```
ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory();
factory.setSuperclass(Dog.class);
factory.setFilter(
        new MethodFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean isHandled(Method method) {
                return Modifier.isAbstract(method.getModifiers());
            }
        }
    );

MethodHandler handler = new MethodHandler() {
    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object self, Method thisMethod, Method proceed, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Handling " + thisMethod + " via the method handler");
        return null;
    }
};

Dog dog = (Dog) factory.create(new Class<?>[0], new Object[0], handler);
dog.bark();
dog.fetch();
```

Which produces this output:

```
Woof!
Handling public abstract void mock.Dog.fetch() via the method handler
```

Edit:

Currently I am using CGLib Enhancer which is included in Spring 3.2.x and I am in doubt about a convenient way and best practices.

Edit:

I have to say that my proxy classes are not spring beans. They are not managed by Spring.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring you would do such a thing with [Spring AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html). It's a much more high-level approach, which under the hood uses either CGLIB or JDK proxies, depending on configuration.

Here's a sample aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect{

    static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);
    @Pointcut("call(* *.*(*)")
    public void methodCall(){}

    @Before("methodCall()")
    public void logMethodCall(Joinpoint jp){
        LOG.debug("About to call method {} with args {}", jp.getSignature(), jp.getArgs());
    }
}
```

The drawbacks are: this only works on public methods of Objects that are managed by Spring.

Comment: My question was a simplified version of my requirement. Actually I need a way to create some proxy classes on demand. The difficult part is that it is an abstract class.